# iOS Cocoapod with git large file storage

Tags: ios, git, cocoapods, git-lfs

I'm working on a component for iOS developers which is distributed as a Cocoapod. We have several versions up and running, and everything worked really nicely so far.

Since the component itself is rather large (it performs OCR, barcode scanning, and several other nontrivial features), when we included bytecode feature, we passed the github limit of 100MB for file size. We solved the problem by moving the file to git large file storage.

However, after this, we couldn't push the cocoapod to the trunk using 
`pod trunk push`

The error we got is the following:

```
Validating podspec
 -> PPBlinkID (1.4.0)
    - ERROR | file patterns: The `preserve_paths` pattern did not match any file.
```

This indicates that the files which are in git lfs cannot be found in pod trunk.

Is it possible to push a cococapod which has some files in git lfs to pod trunk?